# Reinforcement Learning tools

Tags: reinforcement-learning

What is the difference between `Tensorforce`, `Kerasrl`, and `chainerrl` used for **Reinforcement Learning**?
AS far as I've found all three work with `OpenAI` gym environments and have the same reinforcement learning algorithms that have been implemented. Is there a difference in performance?

Comment: My experience is that if you want to play with Atari games with OpenAI gym environments the training can be super long even with GPUs. Some algorithms show their advantages over others after millions of episodes.

Answer (score 1):

they are different Deep learning bank-ends.
TensorFlow , Keras and Chainer are different libraries used for inference of Neural network based AI algorithms.
Open AI is a Reinforcement Learning library.
These are two different technologies.
if you want Reinforcement learning for Tensorflow, back-end and RL tf library, checkout

https://github.com/google/dopamine

This has no connection with OpenAI. Pure Google tech.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: Keras is more "High Level" than tensorflow in the sense that you can write code quicker with Keras but it's less flexible. Checkout this [this post](https://medium.com/implodinggradients/tensorflow-or-keras-which-one-should-i-learn-5dd7fa3f9ca0) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow , keras and Chainer all these are frameworks. These frameworks can be used to implement Deep Reinforcement learning models. As Jaggernaut said Keras is more of high level (meaning : pretty easy to learn) Keras uses Tensorflow backend to function.